# EF Code First : Mapping nontable objects with Fluent API

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

How should I map my nontable objects in EF CodeFirst such as Views, StoredProcedure and etc with fluent API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mapping to store procedure and vew is not supported yet in code first. And these are some work around from Julia Lerman's Programming Entity Framework : Code First.

**Mapping to Updatable View**

`modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().ToTable("MY_VIEW")`

View column names should be the same as Entity field name and you
    can    use the Entity Framework to insert, update, and delete data
    as well    as selecting it. *Just lie to Code First and tell the View
    as Table*.

**Using View to Populate Objects**

`var myEntity = dbContext.MyEntity.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.MY_VIEW")`

View column names should be the same as Entity field names and you still get DbContext features such as change tracking, lazy loading.

**Using View to Populate Nonmodel Objects**

`var myNonModel = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.MY_VIEW")`

View column names should be the same as Entity field names.

**Working With Stored Procedures**

Same technique for working with view.

`var myEntity = dbContext.MyEntity.SqlQuery("dbo.StoredProcedureName @p0 @p1", myParam1, myParam2)`

Answer (score 2):

Mapping of stored procedure is not supported in code first at all. Mapping of views must be hacked - you will pretend that view is a table and hope that your application will work. Fluent-api was designed to support only code-first scenario = your application will create a database. So it doesn't have support for any database features with logic on DB level like stored procedures, views or functions.

Comment: +1: When truly using Code-First, or any question/answer related to true Code-First, The database shouldn't have Views, Functions, or S.P.'s that are used by any application.