# Undesired Migration for Object Mapped to a View

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

**The Problem**

We have an object

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]public virtual int A { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]public virtual int B { get; set; }
}
```

that needs to be mapped to an indexed view in SQL Server.  Building on the approaches

[EF Code First : Mapping nontable objects with Fluent API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939483/ef-code-first-mapping-nontable-objects-with-fluent-api/8942997#8942997) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/20887064/141172

we first created an initial migration

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable("dbo.Foos",
        c => new { A = c.Int(nullable:false), B = c.Int(nullable:false) })
        .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.A, t.B });
}
```

Then an empty migration into which we added SQL to drop the auto-generated table, and then add the index

```
public override void Up()
{
    Sql(@"DROP TABLE Foos");
    Sql(@"CREATE VIEW dbo.Foos As....");
}
```

finally in our DbContext, Foo is mapped to the view:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().ToTable("Foos");
```

This worked just fine, until we added another property to Foo:

```
[Key, Column(Order = 2)]public int C { get; set; }
```

We added a new migration to redefine the view

```
public override void Up()
{
    Sql(@"ALTER VIEW Foos ....");
}
```

The Alter View migration is correctly applied, but EF believes that it must create a migration to account for the new property.

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration.

When I run

```
Add-Migration WhatIsPending
```

EF generates

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Foos");
    AddColumn("dbo.Foos", "C", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Foos", new[] {"A", "B", "C" });
}
```

**Question**

Is there a better approach to mapping an object to a view, such that changes to the object are painless?

If this is the best approach, how can I inform EF Migrations that it does not need to generate the migration?

Comment: Thank you for sharing your way to do this. I think the ToTable("View") hack is the only way to map views to entities. But it seems that migration model hash must match all tables mapped as ToTable(even if it is a view) after each migration. I think that the super hack in 2 migration files will work: First migration: Drop view, Create table again. 2 - Drop table, Create new view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We couldn't find a way to tell EF to not create a migration, but this approach might help:

1. When you create the POCO, don't `CreateTable()` in the migration. if EF wants to create a migration file, fine, but you can comment the code out so only your `Sql(@"Create View ...");` runs.
2. All we had to do then was create the `DbSet` for the view, not a `modelBuilder.Entity` entry.
3. When you need to make changes, start the same way as any other table. Make changes to the POCO, then run `Add-Migration` and let it create the migration for you. comment out whatever it wants to do, and add your `Alter View` script in. make sure you make a corresponding one in the `Down`.

This way you will just have a single migration file for each change.